# Asymptotic distribution of $\frac{1}{n m} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m 1(X_i > Y_j)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X_1, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d. draws of some random variable $X$; likewise, $Y_1, ..., Y_m$ are i.i.d. draws of some random variable $Y$. If we want to estimate $P(X > Y)$, we may consider the fraction of all the $(X_i, Y_j)$ pairs which have the property that $X_i > Y_j$. That is, consider
$$\frac{1}{n m} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m 1(X_i > Y_j) = \frac{1}{n m} \sum_{i, j} 1(X_i > Y_j)$$
where $1$ is the indicator function.

One sees that this is an unbiased estimator of $P(X > Y)$:
$$ E[\frac{1}{n m} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m 1(X_i > Y_j)] = \frac{1}{n m} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m E[1(X_i > Y_j)] = \frac{nm}{nm}P(X > Y) = P(X > Y)$$

I have two (related) questions, however:

(1) Can one show that our estimator is consistent using (something like) the law of large numbers? I'm a bit confused here since the LLN usually applies to a simple sample average (with a single summation).

(2) Can one show that our estimator is asymptotically normal using (something like) the central limit theorem?

Comment: The potential blocker from directly applying these theorems is the fact that some of the addends are correlated. It might be possible to apply more general versions of those theorems though.

Comment: Your statistic is the Mann-Whitney $U$ which is known to be a U-statistic. Reading up on the asymptotics of U-statistics might help.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks, do you have a good reference? I tried looking at the Wikipedia page for the Mann–Whitney U test but the test statistic there looked a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_{n,m}$ be this estimator. I can prove that $P_{n,m}$ is a weakly consistent estimator of $P(X>Y)$. I do not know whether it is strongly consistent or not. I am also unable to determine if $P_{n,m}$ is normal in the limit.

You have shown that $\mathrm E[P_{n,m}]=P(X>Y)$. In order to show $P_{n,m}$ is consistent, we need to show it gets more and more tightly concentrated around its mean as $n,m\to\infty$, so we should look at $\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\Var P_{n,m}$. Note that
$$
\mathrm E[P_{n,m}^2]
=\frac1{n^2m^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{\ell=1}^m 
\mathrm E[1(X_i>Y_j)\cdot 1(X_k>Y_\ell)]
$$

To evaluate this sum, we break into several cases.

- First, deal with the terms where $i\neq k$ and $j\neq \ell$. For each of these terms, $1(X_i>Y_j)$ is independent of $ 1(X_k>Y_\ell)$, so $\mathrm E[1(X_i>Y_j)\cdot 1(X_k>Y_\ell)]=P(X>Y)^2$. There are $(n^2-n)(m^2-m)$ terms like this, which is the overwhelming majority.
- The number of remaining terms is $nm^2+n^2m-nm$. Some of these are too complicated to evaluate exactly. For example, when $i=k$ and $j\neq \ell$, then $ E[1(X_i>Y_j)\cdot 1(X_i>Y_\ell)]$ cannot be expressed in terms of $P(X>Y)$ alone. Therefore, I will just upper bound these terms by $1$.

This implies
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm E[P_{n,m}^2]
&\le  \frac1{n^2m^2}\left[(n^2-n)(m^2-m)\cdot P(X>Y)^2+(nm^2+n^2m-nm)\cdot 1\right]
\\
&= \left(1-\frac1n-\frac1m+\frac1{nm}\right)P(X>Y)^2+\frac1n+\frac1m-\frac1{nm}
\\
&\le P(X>Y)^2 + \mathcal O\left(\frac1{\min(n,m)}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, you get
$$
\Var(P_{n,m})=\mathrm E[P_{n,m}^2]-\mathrm E[P_{n,m}]^2
=\mathcal O\left(\frac1{\min(n,m)}\right)
$$
Since $\Var(P_{n,m})\to 0$ as $n,m\to\infty$, we have shown that $P_{n,m}$ converges to $P(X>Y)$ in mean square as $n\to\infty$. In particular, we have convergence in probability, so that $P_{n,m}$ is a weakly consistent estimator of $P(X>Y)$.